# Как записывать видео тестирования на Facebook WebDriver используя PHP?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

Как записывать видео тестирования на Facebook WebDriver используя PHP? В итоге все равно придется преобразовывать в gif но для начала хочу узнать как можно записать видео?

Answer (score 1):

Начать с того что в штатной поставке Selenium нет функции записи видео. Но её можно добавить отдельно: [selenium-video-node](https://github.com/aimmac23/selenium-video-node/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md).

С этим модулем после каждого теста вы сможете скачать видео по ссылке подобной такой:

```
http://<Hub URL>:4444/grid/admin/HubVideoDownloadServlet/?sessionId=<Driver Session ID>
```

Comment: Это Java, надо для php. Но спасибо. Я решил записывать использую внешнее приложения, запуская и останавливая его через скрипт

Comment: Селениум сам написан на Java...